# Angular 2/4 - Passing multiple parameters in routerLink

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I'm trying to route a link to a page in my Angular application, but always receive the same error.

My Route.ts file has these routes:

```
export const ROUTES : Routes = [

    {path:'',component:AvisosComponent    },
    {path:'gerenciarModeloAviso', component:GerenciaModAvisoComponent },
    {path:'editModeloAviso/:id/:action', component: EditModeloAvisoComponent  }   

]
```

The problem is in the last route, that has two parameters.

And in the html I tried this:

```
<img src="../assets/editarOn.png" alt="Editar" [routerLink]="['/editModeloAviso',estrut.idAvisoEstrutura,'VIEW']" />
```

Then, I tried this:

```
<img src="../assets/editarOn.png" alt="Editar" [routerLink]="['/editModeloAviso',{id:estrut.idAvisoEstrutura,action:'VIEW'}]" />
```

And the error are always the same:

[Error route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBOZu.png)

Just for comment, I changed the route file to this:

```
export const ROUTES : Routes = [

    {path:'',component:AvisosComponent    },
    {path:'gerenciarModeloAviso', component:GerenciaModAvisoComponent },
    {path:'editModeloAviso/:id/action', component: EditModeloAvisoComponent  }   

]
```

( I removed the ":" before the "action" word. Anyway, the error persists. )

If I use just one parameter in the route, It's ok, i have no error. But with two, no way.

Could You help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-v6hehb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did.

Comment: What part of the app you u need in this case? THe destiny page.ts ?  
Just looking to the code that I posted, do you see anything wrong ?

Comment: I don't need a part of the app. I need a complete minimal example, as I just posted, but which actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: what is your angular version 2 or 4?

Comment: I didn't know the stackBlitz. I edited the code, including more content.
https://angular-router-basic-example-khfegh.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Dumal, Angular 4

Comment: when you remove : before action, then you need to replace 'View' with 'action' that is sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you accidentally avoided to use an absolut path in your route.ts. Try this routes

```
export const ROUTES : Routes = [

    {path:'',component:AvisosComponent    },
    {path:'gerenciarModeloAviso', component:GerenciaModAvisoComponent },
    {path:'/editModeloAviso/:id/:action', component: EditModeloAvisoComponent  }   

]
```

in combination with this HTML-Part

```
<img src="../assets/editarOn.png" alt="Editar" [routerLink]="['/editModeloAviso',estrut.idAvisoEstrutura,'VIEW']" />
```

that should do.

Comment: Tried, but give this error in browser console:
Error: Invalid configuration of route '/editModeloAviso/:id/:action': path cannot start with a slash

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're right. This construction is not supposed to work. I mixed something up.

Comment: DiabolicWords, I changed the path, removing the bar and the implementation finally works! 
The correct path is: 
{path:'editModeloAviso/:id/:action', component: EditModeloAvisoComponent  }  

Thanks a lot!